# Unquote key value from Object.fromEntries() result. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, url, key

I'm trying to get a js object from an URL key:value pairs. For that I'm using "Object.fromEntries()" but when I got the result, it returns an object with all the keys quoted, so when I try to access its value I got an error.

Does somebody knows how to solve that, pls?

This is the code:

```
const params = window.location.search;
const obj = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(params))
console.log(obj);
```

...and this is what it returns back:

```
Object { "user-name": "phill", "user-lastname": "smith" }
```

​How can I remove quotes from: user-name and user-lastname keys.?

Comment: The quotes aren't part of the object. That's just the way properties that have special characters are shown.

Comment: You can't remove the quotes, because keys with special characters require quotes. However, you can access them using brackets notation `obj['user-name']`.

Comment: the quotes are just JSON syntax writing rules, real names or value are without quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the quotes, because keys with special characters require quotes. However, you can access them using brackets notation obj['user-name'].

The other option is to get the param from the `URLSearchParams` instance using [`URLSearchParams.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get):

```js
const params = 'user-name=phill&user-lastname=smith';

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(searchParams)

console.log(searchParams.get('user-name'));
console.log(obj['user-name']);
```